# Two separate patterns and matchers (java)

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple bot for discord and the first pattern reading works fine and I get the results I'm looking for, but the second one doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if (event.getMessage().getContent().startsWith("!")) {
        String output, newUrl;
        String word, strippedWord;
        String url = "http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=";
        Pattern reading;
        Matcher matcher;

        word = event.getMessage().getContent();
        strippedWord = word.replace("!", "");
        newUrl = url + strippedWord;

        //Output contains the raw text from jisho
        output = getUrlContents(newUrl);

        //Searching through the raw text to pull out the first "reading: "
        reading = Pattern.compile("\"reading\":\"(.*?)\"");
        matcher = reading.matcher(output);

        //Searching through the raw text to pull out the first "english_definitions: "
        Pattern def = Pattern.compile("\"english_definitions\":[\"(.*?)]");
        Matcher matcher2 = def.matcher(output);

        event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(matcher2.toString());

        if (matcher.find() && matcher2.find()) {
            event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("Reading: "+matcher.group(1)).queue();
            event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("Definition: "+matcher2.group(1)).queue();
        }
        else {
            event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("Word not found").queue();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it'd be helpful if you were to include (1) your expected results and (2) the results you're getting.

Comment: Expecting to get 
"Reading: ---
Definition: ---"

Getting:
Word not found (because of the if bit)

If I leave the if statement out I get an error message after it displays the reading

Comment: You are still not helpful. Please post an example text output and then the text you expect that gets put into Definition: ...

Comment: I'm pulling output from [this](http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97) and I expect to get "Chinese characters","kanji" put into Definition:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to escape the `[` character to `\\[` (once for the Java String and once for the Regex). You also did forget the closing `\"`.

the correct pattern looks like this:

```
Pattern def = Pattern.compile("\"english_definitions\":\\[\"(.*?)\"]");
```

At the output, you might want to readd `\"` and start/end.

```
event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("Definition: \""+matcher2.group(1) + "\"").queue();
```